# Update docker volume when application files changes from new image pull

Tags: docker

I have an angular application with which I created the following docker image:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.13
COPY /dist/myapp /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

I am using docker compose and certbot image to have a SSL certificate:

```
frontend:
    image: myfrontend-image...
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - web-root:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - dhparam:/etc/ssl/certs

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - web-root:/usr/share/nginx/html
    depends_on:
      - frontend
    command: ...
```

I was able to deploy my application with the SSL certificate successfully. The problem is that now I pushed a new version of my frontend but it is not getting deployed.

I believe that the volume web-root is cached by docker and the new files are not overriding the files in the volume.

How can I update my setup so I can keep certbot while also updating my frontend whenever I need to?

Comment: Does Certbot actually need access to your HTML files; or can you delete the `web-root` volume everywhere it appears?  (The pre-existing content in the volume always takes precedence over the image content and it never gets updated.)

Comment: To be honest I loosely followed this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-a-containerized-node-js-application-with-nginx-let-s-encrypt-and-docker-compose
I am not sure but I believe the web-root volume exists so certbot works properly but I am not sure how it all works together.